# Laravel SSH Ouput not returning full output content

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm running the following code using Laravel 4 and the SSH command.

```
SSH::into('runtime')->run(array(
   'cd /home/ubuntu',
   './update.sh'
), function ($line){

   echo $line.PHP_EOL;

});
```

The SSH command works absolutely fine and the contents of the `update.sh` file run. However...

If I run the update.sh script from the command line the output is:

```
Already up-to-date. (This part of the message depends on the output of git pull)
Stopping nginx: nginx.
Starting nginx: nginx.
```

What i'm getting returned when running the Laravel code:

```
nginx.
```

Is there a way to get the full output or does Laravel trim it in anyway?

Comment: Could you please try executing the script in the current shell, like `. ./update.sh` or `source ./update.sh`? Maybe it just can't capture the subshell output...

Comment: Hi @matpop i've run those two commands and the full output appears.

Comment: Hi ajtrichards, have you tried these commands with Laravel? Does the full output appear with Laravel? Any changes?

Comment: Yeah i've run the commands in Laravel and nothing changes :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that was occurring was that the `update.sh` was running 3 commands and the Laravel SSH function was only returning the last part of the output as the variable I was using to capture kept getting overwritten.

I created a private variable in my class:

```
private $output;
```

Then changed my SSH run code to:

```
SSH::into('runtime')->run(array(
   'cd /home/ubuntu',
   './update.sh'
), function ($line){

   $this -> output .= $line.PHP_EOL;

});
```

So for this to work I'm appending the output of `$line` to my output variable. I can then access my output using:

`echo $this -> output;`

That printed everything out

Comment: Hi ajtrichards, does this print all the output lines at once? Or is it in real time? Meaning, if you have a set of 4 commands that are pretty hefty in terms of performance, is the returned value (the output) returned right away or is it only after all of the commands are run? For example, creating copies of a set of files, then building a set of HTML files, then back up those files, then sending those files by email, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try appending to the command a redirection to send stderr to stdout.

```
SSH::into('runtime')->run(array(
    'cd /home/ubuntu',
    './update.sh 2>&1'
), function ($line){
    $this->line($line);
});
```